# Display data from database table in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin in Wordpress which allows users to trade cryptocurrencies.

At this point, I'm trying to get some information from the database because I want to display them.

I want to get an email existing into the custom Wordpress user table and I'm trying with this code:

```
    global $wpdb, $key, $secret, $pass, $email;
    $verifyUser = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM wp_user WHERE user_email = '$email'");
    echo $verifyUser;
```

But it isn't displaying nothing.

Is it there something wrong with the syntax?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `var_dump($verifyUser); die();` to see what `$verifyUser` actually contains.

Comment: It contains NULL, I think SELECT from database isn't working properly

Comment: That is displayed correctly

Comment: do `$sql = "select...` and then `die($sql);`. try using a mysql client to run the resulting query directly on the database.